# How to check string quotes in regex

Tags: regex

In my app I can accept strings like this format:

```
'key':'value'
'key1':'value1'
'key2':'value2'
```

Now I want write a regex pattern to check this format so I write this pattern:

```
/^'(.*)'(:{1})'(.*)?'($|\n)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/oM1qO9/3

This pattern work but if I change the string to below example, work again because select first quote and last quote and so string match with pattern.

```
'key':'value','key1':'value1' 'key2':'value2'
```

https://regex101.com/r/oM1qO9/4

Comment: Replace `.*` with `[^']*` (a single quote inside  a negated character class). [`/^'([^']*)':'([^']*)'$/`](https://regex101.com/r/oM1qO9/6).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not work again, https://regex101.com/r/oM1qO9/5

Comment: You might want a non-greedy consumption: `/^'(.*?)'(:{1})'(.*?)?'($|\n)/gm`

Comment: `{1}` is useless, `(.*)` and `(.*)?` should probably be `(.*?)` to force them being not greedy but the real problem of your `regex` is `($|\n)`. It forces the `regex` match the entire string.

Comment: @MajAfy See my updated comment. However, that won't work if you have escaped quotes in the input. Can there be any escaped quotes? If yes, what is the escaping char? BTW, lazy `.*?` won't work here. You do not need `($|\n)`, just use a multiline modifier to make `$` match at the end of the line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks you right, work but another problem is exists! string should start with `'` now when I insert space first of string the pattern will match again: https://regex101.com/r/oM1qO9/7

Comment: Add `\s*` to allow whitespace where needed. Please review my comments and update the question accordingly to make it clearer. Does https://regex101.com/r/oM1qO9/8 work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` pattern matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible: form the current position to the end of the line, consuming all `'` chars it finds on its way to the line end. Even if you use `.*?` pattern, a lazy quantified dot, it will still go through the `'` to find a valid match (a whole line with at least 4 `'` chars).

So, you need to use negated character class here, `[^']` that matches any char but `'`.

```
/^'([^']*)':'([^']*)'$/
```

Or - to disallow empty key names:

```
/^'([^']+)':'([^']*)'$/
```

Or - to disallow both empty names and values:

```
/^'([^']+)':'([^']+)'$/
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `'` - an apostrophe
- `([^']*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `'`
- `':'` - a literal substring `':'`
- `([^']*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `'`
- `'$` - a `'` at the end of the string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bc1KOu/1).

Note that `*` matches 0 or more occurrences. If you need to match at least one, use `+` instead.

To allow optional whitespaces, add `\s*` everywhere where needed. E.g., you may use

```
/^\s*'([^']*)'\s*:\s*'([^']*)'\s*$/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM1qO9/8).

Comment: For the regex to match, the key and value should both contain at least 1 character. So your suggestion to replace * by ' shouldn't be a suggestion. ;-) Otherwise '':'' matches, which is not a valid key, value pair.

Comment: @mlambrichs: OP does not set the requirement that the name or value should contain at least 1 char. I just modified the existing pattern to show how to make sure there are just 4 single quotes in the string.

Comment: You're right, of course, he/she didn't specify that. But people end up putting empty strings in a database, which I'm just trying to warn for.

Comment: @mlambrichs I answered more than 13K questions about regex. I have seen a lot of weird requirements. I do not want to overthink (I was asked not to a lot of times). If you need to disallow empty input, use `+` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

use `'([^']+)'\s*:\s*'([^']*)'`:
first it matches any non-empty string that does not contain ' between a pair of ', then matches any number of spaces, a colon, and any number of spaces, finally it matches another possibly empty string that does not contain ' between a pair of '.

I assume you only want to capture the key and value, and not the colon, so I removed that capture group.

https://regex101.com/r/nxVAkB/3

Comment: Thanks, I want use this pattern for validation and not for capture strings, so if one term not matched all pattern should return false

Answer (score 0):

Global matching with

```
'(?<key>[^']+)':'(?<value>[^']+)'
```

matches all your examples and giving you - named - results.

Check on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iF4Nu7/1)